# MVC use Razor Variable in JavaScript script in a .cshtml file

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@page
@model HorrorMovieAPI
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@{
    var TMDbKey = GetKey.GetTMDbKey();
    var movieOfTheDay = HorrorMovieAPI.GetMovieInfo(TMDbKey);
    var movieVideo = HorrorMovieAPI.GetVideo(TMDbKey, movieOfTheDay);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>Horror Movie of the Day</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Creepster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link asp-append-version="true" type="text/css" href="~/css/HorrorStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="image-container">

        <header>
            <a class="nav "href="/movie/index">Horror Movie Db</a>
        </header>
        <main>
            <h1 id="title">Horror Movie of the Day</h1>
            <h2 id="movie-title">@movieOfTheDay.title</h2>
            <h3 id="movie-release">@movieOfTheDay.release_date</h3>
            <img src="@movieOfTheDay.poster_path" title="Movie of the day poster." id="movie-poster"/>
            <p id="movie-overview">@movieOfTheDay.overview</p>
            <h3 id="movie-rating">Movie Rating: @movieOfTheDay.vote_average/10</h3>

            @*beginning of iframe*@
            <div id="player"></div>
            <script>
                
                var tag = document.createElement('script');

                tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                //make the C# variable available to JS
                var trailer = '@movieVideo'; *****TROUBLE HERE

                var player;
                function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                  player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    height: '390',
                    width: '640',
                    videoId: trailer, *****TROUBLE HERE
                    playerVars: {
                      'playsinline': 1
                    },
                    events: {
                      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                  });
                }

                function onPlayerReady(event) {
                  event.target.playVideo();
                }

                var done = false;
                function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                    //setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                    done = true;
                  }
                }
                function stopVideo() {
                  player.stopVideo();
                }
            </script>
```

I have a console app that uses the TMDb API call to display some specific info on my index.cshtml, the methods, and TMDb call all work correctly.  I decided I wanted to embed the movie trailer in the index, so the JS script is the YouTube IFrame Player API.  I denoted what I think the issue points are with *****, specifically those because if I take the YouTube video key for the movie trailer and place it directly for the videoId it works as designed.  However, the issue seems to come from assigning the movieVideo C# variable from the Model into the script.  The worst part, this worked when I built it in a different branch but stopped once I merged!

The method that derives the YouTube key works and provides the correct key.  When this code worked, it would load the video on the index page with no issues.  After it stopped working, I tried Html.Raw() but still the same issue.

Comment: Set hidden elements on the page with the values obtained by code. Then let the js code read the hidden elements.